# adding line plot to imshow and changing axis marker

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have made the attached plot using the following codes:

```
a = 1
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,101)
x = np.linspace(-3*a,3*a,1001, dtype='complex')
y = np.linspace(-3*a,3*a,1001, dtype='complex')
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# come manipulations with V
# (same shape and type as X,Y) not shown here 

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.scatter(a*np.cos(theta), a*np.sin(theta))
plt.imshow(V.real)
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.scatter(a*np.cos(theta), a*np.sin(theta))
plt.imshow(V.imag)
plt.colorbar()
```

What I want to do is that:

1) change the scale of the plot such that the horizontal and vertical axis varies between -3*a and 3*a

2) plot the circle boundary (centered at the origin with radius = a). Now it appears at the top left, as the scale of the plot is changed from [-3*a,3*a] to that of the size of the array.[image]

Comment: have you considered using the xlim and ylim commands? I think it should help you with the first issue

Comment: It doesn't work. If I use xlim(-3,3), ylim(-3,3) then it will just zoom in to the top left corner and display the the V[0:3,0:3]

Comment: is V an image? it looks like the x and y coordinates describe rows and columns of an image

Comment: Not sure what's the definition of an 'image', but V is an array of shape 1001x1001.

Comment: You're looking for the `extent` kwarg to `imshow`.

Comment: You can also consider `contourf(x, y, Z)` which happens to be filled contours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you're looking for the `extent` kwarg to `imshow`.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, extent=[10, 30, np.pi, -2*np.pi])
plt.show()
```

[image]

In the case of the example you gave:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 1
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

# We could replace the next three lines with:
# y, x = np.mgrid[-3*a:3*a:1000j, -3*a:3*a:1000j]
x = np.linspace(-3*a, 3*a, 1000)
y = np.linspace(-3*a, 3*a, 1000)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Now let's make something similar to your V for this example..
r = np.hypot(x, y)
V = np.cos(3*np.arctan2(y, x)) + np.sin(r) + np.cos(x)*1j * np.cos(r)

def plot(ax, data):
    ax.plot(a*np.cos(theta), a*np.sin(theta), color='black')
    im = ax.imshow(data, extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.max(), y.min()])
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.5)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax1.set(title='Real Portion')
plot(ax1, V.real)

ax2.set(title='Imaginary Portion')
plot(ax2, V.imag)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, you might also consider using `pcolormesh` in this case. For example, we could change the `plot` function to:

```
def plot(ax, data):
    ax.plot(a*np.cos(theta), a*np.sin(theta), color='black')
    im = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, data)
    ax.set(aspect=1)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.5)
```

The main differences are:

1. `imshow` can interpolate, while `pcolormesh` gives vector output and can't interpolate (i.e. it plots lots of rectangles instead of an image).
2. `pcolormesh` is somewhat slower, so for large images, `imshow` is a better choice.
3. `imshow` and `pcolormesh` treat the extents slightly differently.  `imshow` is "cell-centered" while `pcolormesh` is "mesh-centered".  This is a half-pixel difference, so you can ignore it in this case.
4. `imshow` will set the aspect of the plot to 1, so that one unit in the x-direction is the same size as one unit in the y-direction. It also flips the y-axis, by default.

One other note: If you'd prefer not to have the y-axis flipped, either call `ax.invert_yaxis()` or use `origin='lower'` and `extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]`.