# Marking a point on image from imshow() with the modified axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

My question is very simple. I visualize an 2d array with imshow() and modify its axis ticks and labels. Now, if I need to put a marker wrt the 'new' origin, how do I do it? As you can see, the marker still sits wrt the original origin.

```
plt.imshow(vel_meshXY) #vel_meshXY is a 2D array. Image shown below.

# Manipulating the axis ticks and axis tick labels here. 
ax=plt.gca()
ax_labelLoc = np.arange(0,num_steps, 40); ax.set_xticks(ax_labelLoc); ax.set_yticks(ax_labelLoc)
ax.set_xticklabels(np.linspace(turbine_origin[0]-minusX, turbine_origin[0]+plusX, num_steps)[ax_labelLoc])
ax.set_yticklabels(np.linspace(turbine_origin[1]+plusY, turbine_origin[1]-minusY, num_steps)[ax_labelLoc])

# trying to put a marker wrt the 'new' origin 
ax.plot(10, 10, 'o', markersize= 10, color = 'r')
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, what new origin?

Comment: according to the modified axis that is there in the image.

Comment: The answer to the above question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530520/adding-line-plot-to-imshow-and-changing-axis-marker